# Responding to reviewer comments that doesn't include facts

Tags: paper-submission

During the second revision of a journal paper we received the following comment:

> However; many studies have discussed {topic of the paper}

The reviewer did not list any studies. To the best of our knowledge, there have not been "many studies" addressing the paper's topic. The ones that in our opinion are relevant are discussed in the section on related work.

In this case: **Who has the burden of proof?** It is difficult to respond to such a generic comment that does not include information. It would have been very helpful if the reviewer had listed the studies that are being referred to in the comment.

Comment: Peer review is not a court trial, it should be a helpful conversation, so burden of proof is not really the right concept here. Why not simply politely ask the reviewer (via the editor) for some specific references, remarking of course that you looked for them but have been unable to find more than those you already cited?

Comment: "The reviewer comment prompted us to conduct a second in-depth literature search. However, we were not able to find additional papers beyond those we discuss in related work. We still believe that our manuscript is a valuable contribution to {topic of the paper} because {reasons}." Be sure to check if there is relevant literature from before the existence of Science Direct, Web of Science and co.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, that's great!

Comment: @mlk Thanks for your comment! In the interest of timely publication, I've received advice not to do that as it "risks" another round of reviews :(

Comment: I have written that sort of comment myself.  Usually, the authors do not know the topic exists under a different name; I usually point them in a specific direction.  Also, the topic could be too broad.  For example, 'We propose a machine learning algorithm to do X', but this statement may not be new in itself.  So the authors need to spell out exactly what they claim is new.  Think about a reviewer that Googles topic X and finds thousands of references.  He/she will then conclude that many studies have done X.